# using foreach loop for a mysqli query suggestion

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

hello all i am having a site where people can share their uploaded documents with other people.
right now people can upload one at a time and can have at maximum of 50 documents in their profile each with a check box so that user can select them and can share it with  their friends.

now the problem starts right now i am having no limits (as many users can select documents and can share from 1 to 50)
so on the other page when the user submits the form the action page should enter the data into database 
my question is how to insert all shared document id with the selected userd id.
tabe is not made till now.

i know that i can have it by foreach loop but i think if user selects 50 documets then loop will run 50 times and mysqli query will run 100 times as i need 2 sql query per document one for uniqueness and one for insertion
is there any other method to do this please tell me ...

Answer (score 3):

You can insert multiple values in one query:

```
INSERT INTO `table_name` (`document_id`, `user_id`) VALUES (`1`, `1`), (`2`,`1`), ... (n, m);
```

Comment: but i have the value as like 1,2,3,4,5 and i need to enter them to database individually how do i do it without using loop

Comment: i dont know the document id they are coma seperated

Comment: @Rahulaman you need to learn how to manipulate your data, and then build the SQL syntax from the answer above.